# No main JAR file specified

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a middle tier app using JWS to download the jar to execute.  On one computer I goto the webpage and everything works as expected.  The jar is downloaded and runs perfectly.  I go to another computer and it fails with the following error

```
JNLPException[category: Launch File Error : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
<jnlp spec="1.6+" codebase="http://server03-xtx-02:8080/App">
  <information>
    <title>someApp One Launch</title>
    <vendor>Worldwide International, Inc.</vendor>
    <homepage href="docs/help.html"/>
    <description>someApp OneLauncher</description>
    <description kind="short">someApp .</description>
    <icon href="images/someApp.jpg"/>
    <icon href="images/Splash.jpg" kind="splash"/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources arch="amd64">
    <j2se version="1.8" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
    <j2se version="1.7" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
    <j2se version="1.6" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
    <jar href="jnlplib/onelauncher.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.wi.App.launch.OneLauncher">
    <argument>1</argument>
    <argument>http://server03-xtx-02:8081/App</argument>
    <argument>null</argument>
    <argument>false</argument>
    <argument>Tools--QA</argument>
    <argument>ms_vars:=false</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp> ]
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried comparing both computers and nothing is sticking out as to why one would work and another wouldn't.  I feel like this could be a red herring but am at a loss to where I should dig next.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing your JWS cache by Control Panel -> Programs -> Java

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that didn't resolve the issue though.

Comment: did you clear the cache ??

Comment: Yep, went Java Control Panel and deleted temporary internet files.

Comment: does the other machine match arch=amd64 and has java >= 1.6 installed?

Comment: you shall follow http://www.javiies.com/how-to-fix-jnlpexceptioncategory-launch-file-error-exception-null-launchdesc-error/

Comment: Both machines are the same.  Both have 1.6 and 1.8 32 bit installed and 1.8 installed.  I think I found the issue but I'm not sure how to rectify.  one machine had jnlp and jnlpFile associated to java8 64 bit and it worked.  The other pc had those files assocaited to java8 32 bit and is causing that error.  I think I need to find a way to make our application run only in 64bit without disturbing those files being associated to 32 bit java.  Not sure if that is possible.